# Sed replace substring only if expression exist

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I am trying to remove the directory name in filenames :

```
documents/file.txt
direc/file5.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

So I try to first see if there is a "/" and if yes delete everything before :

```
for i in **/*.scss *.scss; do
    echo "$i" | sed -n '^/.*\// s/^.*\///p'
done
```

But it doesn't work for files in the current directory, it gives me a blank string.

I get :

```
file.txt
file5.txt
```

Comment: How did you get on with this, Louis?

Comment: please my answer below

Comment: OK, great - thanks for adding a self-answer. The purpose of my comment was to encourage you to interact with your helpers, by either upvoting, accepting or commenting on their work. None of that is mandatory here, in the same way that politeness is not mandatory in real life, but anything that encourages helpful people to be helpful again is worth doing, in my view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually, I did :

```
for i in **/*.scss *.scss; do
    # for i in *.scss; do
# for i in _hm-globals.scss; do

    name=${i##*/} # remove dir name
    name=${name%.scss} # remove extension
    name=`echo "$name" | sed -n "s/^_hm-//p"` # remove _hm-
    if [[ $name = *"."* ]]; then
        name=`echo "$name" | sed -n 's/\./-/p'`  #replace . to --
    fi

    echo "$name" >&2
done
```

Answer (score 2):

When you only want the filename, use `basename` instead of `sed`.

```
# basename /path/to/file
```

returns `file`

- [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) is the man page

Answer (score 0):

This also can be done with `awk` bash util.

Example:

`echo "1/2/i.py" | awk 'BEGIN  {FS="/"} {print $NF}'
output: i.py`

Answer (score 0):

Your `sed` attempt is basically fine, but you should print regardless of whether you performed a substitution; take out the `-n` and the `p` at the end. (Also there was an unrelated syntax error.)

Also, don't needlessly loop over all files.

```
printf '%s\n' **/*.scss *.scss |
sed -n 's%^.*/%%p'
```